# in flutter getting error:- The getter iterator was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When new user enters in app it throws this error,

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(242)] Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
 E/flutter (30955): Receiver: null
```

And when user add images then there is no error. Here is code where error takes me on clicking. I have commented next to line(third line). Pls help me out. Thanks.

```
Future<List<String>> getImages(BuildContext context) async {
var document = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").
doc(widget.currentUser.uid).get(); ///error takes me inside get()'
List<String> images = [];
for (var item in document.data()['images']) {
  images.add(item);
}
imageList= images;
print(imageList.length);
print(imageList);
return images;
```

}

Comment: Please change the type to `Document Snapshot` instead of `var`. After that use document in for loop. Try this. Also use `if(!document.hasdata)` before for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure images are not null.

```
if(document.data()['images'] != null){
for (var item in document.data()['images']) {
images.add(item);
}
}
```